# Spring boot application specific external properties

Tags: spring, tomcat, properties, spring-boot

I'm seeking solution for this problem.

I have several property files(application.properties, application-realdb.properties). Let's say I'm starting with "realdb" spring profile. Now I want to override my properties when deployed on tomcat.
I decided to put the file to /lib folder as it is automatically on classpath and I didn't found any better(ie app specific classpath folder)

So I can place there application.properties, which will work so long as I will have only one application. In case I have multiple spring boot application I'd like to name the file(NOTE: application specific naming)

- I can use app. specific spring profile and add /lib/application-appname.properies, which includes the necessity to pass the proper profile
- I can use --spring.config.name, which I don't like as well for the need of passing it in command line(I'm not aware of possibility to do it in the war file, maybe set system property in spring boot main class?)
- in @ConfigurationProperties(locations = "classpath:appname.properties, prefix..." it works as I want it is overriden properly, but only for the class I'm binding the values.

Sum up:
Is there a way how to copy specificly named file on classpath and, thus override
application.properties????

**UPDATED**
Proposed solution works I can now use different properties name, but I still have problem with loading files in classpath outside.

```html
Adding [applicationConfig: [classpath:/my-app-realdb.properties]] PropertySource with search precedence immediately lower than [applicationConfigurationProperties]
Adding [applicationConfig: [classpath:/config/my-app.properties]] PropertySource with search precedence immediately lower than [applicationConfig: [classpath:/my-app-realdb.properties]]
Adding [applicationConfig: [classpath:/my-app.properties]] PropertySource with search precedence immediately lower than [applicationConfig: [classpath:/config/my-app.properties]]
```

the last one is in .war, I quess the /lib/config folder should have precedence

```
3. A classpath /config package
4. The classpath root
```

So the hunt for answer is still on

**UPDATE2**
Looks like the order is

```
1. /config/application-<profile_specific>.properties
2. /application-<profile_specific>.properties
3. /config/application.properties
4. /application.properties
```

This means I cannot override, all with non-profile specific properties, which maybe is as intended, but for me, if I want just one file to rule them all not very useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can configure the `spring.config.name` property in your main class, either in the `main` method when running as an executable archive or in the `configure` method when being deployed as a war. For example:

```
@SpringApplication
public class SampleApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SampleApplication.class)
            .properties("spring.config.name:my-app");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(SampleApplication.class)
            .properties("spring.config.name:my-app").build().run(args);
    }

}
```

With this change in place Boot will look for files named `my-app.properties` and `my-app-{profile}.properties`.

Comment: This is exactly the same result i found out, anyway I like this syntax _properties("spring.config.name:my-app")_ more than passing Maps, thank you!!

Comment: Strange thing, it is not able to read my-app.properties from <catalina-home>/lib/my-app.properties, I tried as well application.properties. Nothing. Maybe this solution brokes something:-/

Comment: I suspect that you've misunderstood how Tomcat's class loading works. If you have a my-app.properties file in your war file, placing a file with the same name in Tomcat's lib directory will not override it as Tomcat looks in the war file first and only looks in lib if it doesn't find anything in the war. You can change this behaviour and make it look in lib first by setting `delegate=true` on the web application class loader. See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html for more information.

Comment: So only solution, if you want to use application.properties outside(or renamed version) is: not to use profile specific files and I mean even in your deployable. I will anyway accept the answer above as it solved majority of the problem for me.