# Setting "spring.config.name" property programmatically does not work

Tags: java, spring-boot

According to [this blog post](http://roufid.com/rename-spring-boot-application-properties/#programmatically) from December 2017, it is possible to change the name used to search for Spring Boot configuration files programmatically like this:

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)
            .properties("spring.config.name:conf")
            .build()
            .run(args);
    }
}
```

I have tried this using Spring Boot version **1.5.9-RELEASE**, but this does not work. Setting `spring.config.name` as an argument does work:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.config.name=conf
```

However, I do not have control over the arguments passed to my Spring Boot application when it is started so this is not an option.

Is it no longer possible to set `spring.config.name` programmatically, am I missing something, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't directly answer the question, but I eventually discovered a workaround. Setting the `spring.config.name` by adding it to the arguments does work:

```
package com.ups.cep;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> arguments = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(args));
        arguments.add("-Dspring.config.name=conf");
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, arguments.toArray(new String[arguments.size()]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example works for me (Spring Boot 2.4.3) so it could be bug at that time.

A similar [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28320283/1061929) also uses `SpringApplicationBuilder.properties(String... defaultProperties)` to define configuration name.

```
new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)
        .properties("spring.config.name:conf")
        .build()
        .run(args);
```

I checked both `spring.config.name=conf` and `spring.config.name:conf` and they work.